# for_each in prometheus expression on terraform

Tags: terraform, prometheus, grafana

I am trying to use `for_each` in Prometheus Grafana rule in my Terraform resource. Original working expression is:

```
expr = "avg by(horizontalpodautoscaler) (kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_max_replicas{namespace=\"namespace-x\"})"
```

however I wanted to re-use it for multiple namespaces:

```
expr = "avg by(horizontalpodautoscaler) (kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_max_replicas{namespace=\"$${each.value[\"namespace\"]}\"})"
```

however it is not rendering values from variable returning:

```
+ expr = "avg by(horizontalpodautoscaler) (kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_max_replicas{namespace=\"${each.value[\"namespace\"]}\"})"
```

in plan.

resource is being used in module between multiple accounts having different values within the same variable:

```
variable "namespace" {
  description = "namespace"
  type        = map(object({
    namespace = string
  }))
  default = {
    "1" = {
      namespace = "x"
    }
    "2" = {
      namespace = "y"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to escape it properly and make Terraform to render it properly?

Comment: I'm not sure how prometheus expressions are used in terraform, but wouldn't this do what you want: `avg by(horizontalpodautoscaler, namespace) (kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_max_replicas)`?

Comment: @markalex query itself will work but I don't want all available namespaces, just these listed in variable. What I am looking for is to squeeze `each` somehow.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. In prometheus query for some list of label values is usually this way: `kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_max_replicas{namespace=~"ns1|ns2|new_ns"}`. Maybe you could produce such query?

Comment: @markalex Again that will work but in the case where the single resource is being used as a module for multiple accounts having different variable values.

Comment: @markalex I have updated description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of the `$$` syntax in a string interpolation within Terraform escapes the `$` character, and therefore does not interpolate as a HCL2 variable. You need to remove the extraneous `$` character. Also, HCL2 will properly intrinsically escape `"` characters within a variable resolution expression, and so we must also remove the extra escapes for `"` as they would be a syntax error:

```
expr = "avg by(horizontalpodautoscaler) (kube_horizontalpodautoscaler_spec_max_replicas{namespace=\"${each.value["namespace"]}\"})"
```

This will interpolate the string as desired.

Comment: No, that won't work at all. I've started from that only to get: `│ On x.tf line 179: This character is not used within the language.`

Comment: @SynRomana I reverted my answer from the correct to an incorrect. I unreverted back to the correct as you typed that comment.